# How do I define a GitHub action?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to play around with GitHub actions but I'm having a hard time just have it to start.

As a first step, I have copied the following workflow on a brand new repo.
https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-docker-container-action#example-using-a-private-action

But I get a parsing error

https://github.com/inforlife/action-test/blob/master/.github/main.workflow
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inforlife/action-test/master/.github/main.workflow?token=AA3RFK7OVCNLSMBMVHK6GB25SKZRQ

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 4):

The `.github/main.workflow` HCL format is GitHub Actions version 1. This version no longer works. GitHub Actions version 2 uses yaml format workflows under `.github/workflows/`.

Try starting with these starter workflows
https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned `.github/main.workflow`

[The documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-docker-container-action#example-using-a-private-action) suggests:

```
 .github/workflows/main.yml
```

Adding that main.yml with `.github/workflows/` should work better.

Comment: It may work better but I don't think that is the reason of my issue since this works https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inforlife/action-test/64fbd5650fb0cb506e014f6f0ea05af04bf77e0c/.github/main.workflow?token=AA3RFK5ULZZ6CENOUD3PVEC5SLPDG

thanks

Comment: @Sig 1/ https://github.com/inforlife/action-test/ appears to be a private repo, so I am not able to see much.

Comment: @Sig  2/ your raw.githubusercontent URL includes a token that I don't think you want public: it does allow me to see your second file, which I should not, since it seems to be a private repo.

Comment: @Sig3/ Even with that token, I still get a 404 not found when trying to access your master/.github/main.workflow file.